# Count Data from Database using stored Procedure w/ inner join

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having a problem counting data w/ inner join.

I want to count how many cottages are available, here are my tables:

[image]

[image]

here's my code in class getting the cottage number.

```
public void CheckCottages()
 {
     con.Close();
     SqlCommand comUmbrella = new SqlCommand("CountCottages", con);
     comUmbrella.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     comUmbrella.Parameters.Add("@CottageType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Umbrella";
     comUmbrella.Parameters.Add("@ReservedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = this.ARRIVAL;
     con.Open();
     comUmbrella.ExecuteNonQuery();
     drUmbrella = comUmbrella.ExecuteReader();
     if (drUmbrella.Read())
     {
         this.UMBRELLA = drUmbrella.GetInt32(drUmbrella.GetOrdinal("Rows"));
     }
     con.Close();
     SqlCommand comNativeKubo = new SqlCommand("CountCottages", con);
     comNativeKubo.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     comNativeKubo.Parameters.Add("@CottageType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Native Kubo";
     comNativeKubo.Parameters.Add("@ReservedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = this.ARRIVAL;
     con.Open();
     comNativeKubo.ExecuteNonQuery();
     drKubo = comNativeKubo.ExecuteReader();
     if (drKubo.Read())
     {
         this.NATIVEKUBO = drKubo.GetInt32(drKubo.GetOrdinal("Rows"));
     }
     con.Close();
     SqlCommand comTreeHouse = new SqlCommand("CountCottages", con);
     comTreeHouse.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     comTreeHouse.Parameters.Add("@CottageType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Tree house";
     comTreeHouse.Parameters.Add("@ReservedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = this.ARRIVAL;
     con.Open();
     comTreeHouse.ExecuteNonQuery();
     drTree = comTreeHouse.ExecuteReader();
     if (drTree.Read())
     {
         this.TREEHOUSE = drTree.GetInt32(drTree.GetOrdinal("Rows"));
     }
     con.Close();
     SqlCommand comPavillion = new SqlCommand("CountCottages", con);
     comPavillion.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     comPavillion.Parameters.Add("@CottageType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Pavillion";
     comPavillion.Parameters.Add("@ReservedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = this.ARRIVAL;
     con.Open();
     comPavillion.ExecuteNonQuery();
     drPavillion = comPavillion.ExecuteReader();
     if (drPavillion.Read())
     {
         this.PAVILLION = drPavillion.GetInt32(drPavillion.GetOrdinal("Rows"));
     }
 }
```

Here's my stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.CountCottages
(
    @CottageType nvarchar(50),
    @ReservedDate datetime
)

AS
SELECT count(dbo.Cottages.CottageName)
FROM dbo.Cottages INNER JOIN
dbo.ResortTransactions ON dbo.Cottages.CottageID = dbo.ResortTransactions.CottageID
where dbo.Cottages.CottageType=@CottageType and dbo.ResortTransactions.Status != 'Cancelled' and dbo.ResortTransactions.ReservedDate != @ReservedDate

RETURN
```

What's wrong to my code? I hope someone can help me :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your problem? You get exception, get wrong number or what?

Comment: What's the error/bad result?  What result are you wanting to get?

Comment: i get wrong number i always get 0! :(

Comment: I want to get the number of Cottages Available on the given ReservedDate if The ReservedDate != to the ReservedDate in the Database , the CottageID on the ResortTransactions will be counted to the Number of Cottages Available

Comment: Some people have no sense of humor...

Comment: sorry! :) i'm a newbie in programming! :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there's not much information about *how* your data is used, here's a guess.  I'm assuming you want a count of cottages where there is a transaction where 1) the status is not cancelled and 2) the date is equal to the reservation date.  If so here's the query:

```
SELECT count(dbo.Cottages.CottageName)
    FROM dbo.Cottages 
    WERE CottageType=@CottageType 
        AND CottageID NOT IN
        (SELECT CottageID FROM dbo.ResortTransactions
         WHERE Status != 'Cancelled' 
         AND ReservedDate = @ReservedDate)
```

Also you are executing the sproc twice - once using `ExecuteNonQuery` and once using `ExecuteReader` You should either *return* a value and use `ExecuteNonQuery`, creating a parameter to store the return value, or use `ExecuteScalar` to quickly pull the first result from the dataset.

I would suggest reading up more on basic SQL and how to execute queries with .NET.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the `COUNT`.

Declare a variable, initialize it with the result and return it from the procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.CountCottages
(
    @CottageType nvarchar(50),
    @ReservedDate datetime
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @NumCottages int
SELECT @NumCottages = count(dbo.Cottages.CottageName)
FROM dbo.Cottages INNER JOIN
dbo.ResortTransactions ON dbo.Cottages.CottageID = dbo.ResortTransactions.CottageID
where dbo.Cottages.CottageType=@CottageType and dbo.ResortTransactions.Status != 'Cancelled' and dbo.ResortTransactions.ReservedDate != @ReservedDate

RETURN @NumCottages

END
```

Then use [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) instead of `ExecuteNonQuery` to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

`Cmd.ExeceuteNonQuery()` is normally used to execute a procedure without expecting a result  back. 
But here you are looking for a scalar value.So Change it to `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`.Also return the count back from the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make a few assumptions - just a small tip whilst playing with this I would create a "scratch pad" in a SQL query and use table variables to test with as you can see below:

```
DECLARE @Cottages AS TABLE
    (
      Cottage_PK INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      CottageName VARCHAR(100) ,
      CottageType VARCHAR(100)
    )
DECLARE @Reservations AS TABLE
    (
      Reservation_PK INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      Cottage_FK INT ,
      CheckinDate DATETIME ,
      DepatureDate DATETIME ,
      IsCanceled BIT
    )
DECLARE @DateToCheck AS DATETIME ,
    @CottageType AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @DateToCheck = '2012-09-15'
SET @CottageType = 'Some Type'
INSERT  INTO @Cottages
        ( CottageName, CottageType )
VALUES  ( 'CottageA', 'Some Type' )
INSERT  INTO @Reservations
        ( Cottage_FK ,
          CheckinDate ,
          DepatureDate ,
          [Status]
        )
VALUES  ( 1 , -- Cottage_FK - int
          '2012-09-16' , -- CheckinDate - datetime
          '2012-09-24' ,  -- DepatureDate - datetime
          ''
        )
```

Now I took the assumption that if you want to check cottages availible on a date you would need to check in accordance to the checkin date and the depature date which results in using a `between` statement.

```
SELECT  COUNT(c.CottageName) AS 'Cottages availible'
FROM    @Cottages c
        INNER JOIN @Reservations r ON c.Cottage_PK = r.Cottage_FK
WHERE   NOT @DateToCheck BETWEEN r.CheckinDate
                         AND     r.DepatureDate
        AND c.[status] != 'Cancelled'
        AND c.CottageType = @CottageType
```

Use this for testing - I passed a date within the range it it returned 0 and out of the range and it returned 1. Once your happy move this to your stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CountCottages
    @DateToCheck DATETIME ,
    @CottageType VARCHAR(100)
AS 
    SELECT  COUNT(c.CottageName) AS 'Cottages availible'
    FROM    Cottages c
            INNER JOIN ResortTransactions r ON c.Cottage_PK = r.Cottage_FK
    WHERE   NOT @DateToCheck BETWEEN r.CheckinDate
                             AND     r.DepatureDate
            AND c.[status] != 'Cancelled'
            AND c.CottageType = @CottageType
```